# How to dynamically modify the position of Android Dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-dialog

[If: This is a pop-up dialog by default in the bottom of the window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJwDv.png)
[When I click the input box, how to make the top of the dialog dynamic rise of the keyboard, not just the keyboard is blocked?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHWc6.png)

Comment: [First Picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/pJwDv.png)

Comment: [second picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/FHWc6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the x,y position of dialog:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder (this);

//set your builder
AlertDialog dialog = builder.Create ();
dialog.Window.Attributes.X = 34;
dialog.Window.Attributes.Y = 17;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

 AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
 dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
 WindowManager.LayoutParams wmlp = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
```

wmlp.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
 wmlp.x = 100;   //x position`enter code here`
 wmlp.y = 100;   //y position

dialog.show();